# Map location testing on Android Emulator browser does not work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, geolocation, maps

I am working on a maps web app that uses maps.google.com for Android. On real devices, everything seems to work fine. But on an emulator, I am unable to fix location. However, the Google Maps app works fine and is able to fix the location but not the web page.

I have tried the following:

1. Tried "Geo Fix..." command via Telnet
2. Tried fixing location using DDMS
3. Tried both Android and Google APIs (most of the versions from 8 to 17.)
4. Tried Arm and Intel images.

Steps to recreate:

1. On the emulator, open the stock browser.
2. Navigate to http://maps.google.com.
3. When prompted allow "Share Location".
4. Make sure location is enabled via GPS and Wireless options thru Settings | Location and Privacy settings.
5. Geo fix thru telnet or DDMS.
6. Click on the location icon.

You will get "Location cannot be determined."

Any thoughts or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did u set the permissions correctly. AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: This is mobile web and not an Android app. So no place for AndroidManifest.xml.